# Fast calculation of cosine similarity of one vector with many

Tags: c++, r, performance, vector, rcpp

I'm keen to hear ideas for optimising code to compute the cosine similarity of a vector `x` (with length `l`) with `n` other vectors (stored in any structure such as a matrix `m` with `n` rows and `l` columns).

Values for `n` will typically be much larger than values for `l`.

I'm currently using this custom Rcpp function to compute the similarity of a vector `x` to each row of a matrix `m`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cosine_x_to_m(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix m) {
  int nrows = m.nrow();
  NumericVector out(nrows);
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    NumericVector y = m(i, _);
    out[i] = sum(x * y) / sqrt(sum(pow(x, 2.0)) * sum(pow(y, 2.0)));
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Varying `n` and `l`, I'm getting the following sorts of timings:

[image]

Reproducible code below.

---

```
# Function to simulate data
sim_data <- function(l, n) {
  # Feature vector to be used for computing similarity
  x <- runif(l)

  # Matrix of feature vectors (1 per row) to compare against x
  m <- matrix(runif(n * l), nrow = n)

  list(x = x, m = m)
}

# Rcpp function to compute similarity of x to each row of m
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector cosine_x_to_m(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix m) {
  int nrows = m.nrow();
  NumericVector out(nrows);
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    NumericVector y = m(i, _);
    out[i] = sum(x * y) / sqrt(sum(pow(x, 2.0)) * sum(pow(y, 2.0)));
  }
  return out;
}')    

# Timer function
library(microbenchmark)
timer <- function(l, n) {
  dat <- sim_data(l, n)
  microbenchmark(cosine_x_to_m(dat$x, dat$m))
}

# Results for grid of l and n
library(tidyverse)
results <- cross_d(list(l = seq(200, 1000, by = 200), n = seq(500, 4000, by = 500))) %>% 
  mutate(timings = map2(l, n, timer))

# Plot results
results_plot <- results %>%
  unnest(timings) %>% 
  mutate(time = time / 1000000) %>%  # Convert time to seconds
  group_by(l, n) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(time), ci = 1.96 * sd(time) / sqrt(n()))

pd <- position_dodge(width = 20)

results_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, mean, group= l)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(l)), position = pd, size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci, ymax = mean + ci), position = pd, width = 100) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "n", y = "Seconds", color = "l") +
  ggtitle("Algorithm Runtime",
          subtitle = "Error bars represent 95% confidence intervals")
```

Comment: This is a bit more appropriate for CodeReview than SO.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've opened the question on CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159396/optimizing-cosine-similarity-of-one-vector-with-many

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Microsoft R (with Intel MKL) which makes matrix multiplications faster, but for fair comparison I set it to be single threaded.

```
setMKLthreads(1)
```

In my tests this pure R version `cosine_x_to_m` is twice faster than yours.

```
cosine_x_to_m2 = function(x,m){
  x = x / sqrt(crossprod(x));
  return(  as.vector((m %*% x) / sqrt(rowSums(m^2))) );
}
```

Rewriting `rowSums(m^2)` in C/C++ makes it even faster, about four times faster than the original.

```
library(ramwas)
cosine_x_to_m2 = function(x,m){
  x = x / sqrt(crossprod(x));
  return(  as.vector((m %*% x) / sqrt(rowSumsSq(m))) );
}
```

Initial performance:

[image: Initial performance]

Final version performance:

[image: Final version performance]

Comment: Thanks for great response! As recommended by moderators, I've moved the question to CodeReview. Would you mind moving your answer over there too? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159396/optimizing-cosine-similarity-of-one-vector-with-many

Comment: Can you accept it in both locations?

Comment: Yes, because I just copied and pasted question (not an official move). But I think it's preferable to not vote/accept on this question anymore, and do so in the CodeReview section. Perhaps it's best that I delete this question from SO now?

Comment: I disagree with moderators. 
I'm ok with you not accepting the answer here, but do not support deleting it.